# Is cardinality of the set of real number between 0 and 1 that doesn't have some specific digit string in some specific base decidable?

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, set-theory, computational-mathematics, decidability

Originally, I get this idea when I try to create intermediate cardinality set between the integers and the real numbers to disprove the continuum hypothesis when I read the normal number definition.
However, once I found it that continuum hypothesis is unproveable, at first, I am about to abandon it but then I come up with another question about it instead.

I call it simply "the no specific digit string number".

For here, I will use (10) as 10th digit symbol instead of A, (11) as 10th digit symbol instead of B, and so on.
That mean (11)1 is string of 1 "(11) digit" and 1 "1 digit" (or B1 in normal base number writing).

"the no specific digit string number" is any set of number that

- That is real number between 0 and 1 (but not equal to 0 and 1)
- When write those number in B(n) base when $B(n) ∈ B \text{ & } B ⊆ I^{+}$, it doesn't contain any digit string that is member of set A(n) when $A(n) ∈ A$

  - A(n) and B(n) refer to $n^{th}$ memeber of set A and B.
  - A is the set that contain many smaller set A(n).
  - The cardinality of the set A and B must be same.
  - A and B can be infinite but must be countable set.
  - All digit string that is member of set A(n) must be possible to be appear B(n) base.

    - Note : It doesn't make any different for such a set of number that doesn't contain string 34 when write in base 2 because base 2 never contain string 34.
  - The digit string that is member of set A(n) can be infinite string as long as it can appaear in B(n) base for example digit string of $\pi$ in base 2 when B(n) = 5.
  - A(n) and B(n) must be computable. There must be exist computable algorithm function to generate each digit string that is member of set A(n) and the number in B(n).

    - Note : If they are uncomputable, they will make the "the no specific digit string number" obviously undecidable.

Note that the 0 before the "." doesn't count. For example, "0.1" doesn't have 0 digit string here because it can be write as ".1"

The definition of set A(n) is pretty complicate. I am sorry if I might miss something about A(n). I will fix it as much as I can.

For example,

- B = {10,17,31} & A = {{5},{4,56},{7,(11),23(14)}} mean the set of any real number between 0 and 1 that

  - Doesn't contain string 5 when write in base 10
  - Doesn't contain string 4 and 56 when write in base 17
  - Doesn't contain string 7,(11) and 23(14) when write in base 31
- B = {$x^{2}|x∈I^{+},x>1$} & A = {the set of string "a" that write in base 10 and $\lfloor \frac{B(n)}{2} \rfloor < a < B(n)$} mean the set of any real number between 0 and 1 that

  - Doesn't contain string 3 when write in base 4
  - Doesn't contain string 5,6,7,8 when write in base 9
  - Doesn't contain string 9,10,11,12,13,14,15 when write in base 16
  - ...
  - Doesn't contain digit $\lfloor \frac{B(n)}{2} \rfloor$,$\lfloor \frac{B(n)}{2} \rfloor$+1,...,$n^2-2$,$n^2-1$ when write in base $n^2$
- B = {prime number that is larget than 4} & A = {the set of string "a" that write in base 2 and $a = n$} mean the set of any real number between 0 and 1 that

  - Doesn't contain string 1 when write in base 5
  - Doesn't contain string 10 when write in base 7
  - Doesn't contain string 11 when write in base 11
  - Doesn't contain string 100 when write in base 13
  - Doesn't contain string 101 when write in base 17
  - ...
  - Doesn't contain string of n when write in base 2 when write in base the prime number $p_{n+2}$

With some specific set A and B, I can create empty set, finite set, infinite countable set or uncountable set. For example,

- B = {3} & A = {{0,1,2}} : I will get empty set because there is no number that doesn't contain string 0,1,2 when write in base 3
- B = {3} & A = {{0,1,2222}} : I will get finite set that is {0.2,0.22,0.222}
- B = {3} & A = {{0,1}} : I will get infinite countable set that is {0.2,0.22,0.222,0.2222,...}
- B = {3} & A = {{0}} : I will get uncountable countable set that is {0.1,0.12,0.21,0.121,...,0.12112111211112...,...}

Back to the original question, is cardinality of my "the no specific digit string number" decidable ?
Is it possible to construct an algorithm that always tell whether "the no specific digit string number" is empty set, finite set, infinite countable set or uncountable set when giving any A(n) and B(n) that follow th rule above ?

I know that my "the no specific digit string number" is very broad and can create many varity of set. But for I think it can divide into these case

- (1.) A and B is finite. All A(n) is finite.
- (2.) A and B is finite. Some A(n) is infinite.
- (3.) A and B is finite. All A(n) is infinite.
- (4.) A and B is infinite. All A(n) is finite.
- (5.) A and B is infinite. Some A(n) is infinite.
- (6.) A and B is infinite. All A(n) is infinite.

I think (1.) is decidable and (6.) is undecidable but I am not sure for other case.

Comment: I did not quite get the question. But let us consider an example : Is the digit string $123456\cdots 96979899100$ in $\pi$ in base $10$ ? If this is the case, we will eventually find it. But if this string is NOT in $\pi$ , how shall we find this out ? I doubt that there is an algorithm for this. If $\pi$ is does not conatin every finite digit string , I guess that the problem "Is the string S in $\pi$" is undecidable.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand the 123456⋯96979899100 string. Is 123456⋯96979899100 finite ? Since we know that π is normal number, that mean any finite string in base 10 will contain in π. However, if string is infinite, for example, string of 1/3 or 333.... , it will not contain in π unless that infinite is string of π that start from some its digit.

Comment: 1. Yes the string is finite. It concatenates the numbers from $1$ to $100$ 2. We do not KNOW whether $\pi$ is normal. In fact , we do not know whether the digit $7$ appears infinite many often. And not even whether $\pi$ ends eventually only in digits $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Peter Oh, sorry. I thought π because I see many website and people say it is normal. So, maybe your question is really undecidable as you say. However, my question isn't about specific number. It is about is there any number with that condition. We might not know if π contain that string or not but we know that there are uncountable real number which doesn't contain that string.

Comment: So, do I understand correctly, that for every base from $2$ to infinity you have some (uniformly in base) computable set of finite strings, and you are interested in set of numbers that, when written in any base, don't contain any forbidden for this base string?

Comment: @mihaild That will one of the case (4.), (5.) or (6.) when A and B is infinite. The list of base can be finite which will be case (1.), (2.) or (3.). And I am interest in that is there any algorithm to determine if the set of numbers that don't contain any forbidden for this base string is empty set, finite set, infinite countable set or uncountable set ?

Comment: @mihaild It can also be "every even number base from 2
 to infinity" or "every prime number base from 2
 to infinity" or whatever as long as the list of the base are computable. And string can be infinite strings as long as that string is computable as well. It depend on which case your ask for.

Comment: So, you consider finite and infinite number of bases, and for each base you forbid finite or infinite number of strings (allowing some bases have finite number of restrictions and some infinite is easily equivalent to having always infinite number of restrictions)? And each forbidden string can be finite or infinite. Is this correct?

Comment: @mihaild Yes, that is it can whatever as long as it is A(n) and B(n) is computable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undecidable even in (1). For Turing machine $M$, let $B = \{2\}$, and $A_M = \{\{00, 11, x_M\}\}$ where $x_M[k]$ is $0$ if $M$ stops in at most $k$ steps, and $k \pmod 2$ otherwise - so $x_M$ is $010101\ldots$ if $M$ never stops, and $0101\ldots 0000\ldots$ otherwise.

Forbidding $00$ and $11$ means that we allow only numbers $010101\ldots$ and $101010\ldots$. If $M$ never stops, $x_M$ also forbids them, and we get an empty set. If $M$ does stop, we allow them and get two-element set. So, checking if we have empty set or finite set is the same as solving halting problem for $M$.

If you forbid infinite strings, then (1) is decidable, but the rest are still not.

Note that finite number of finite restrictions in base $b$ can be transformed to finite number of finite restrictions in base $b\cdot k$. So, if we have finite number of finite restrictions in finite number of bases, we can transform them to the same base. Now, we have finite number of finite restrictions in one base. We can transform this restrictions to minimal DFA, and string is in the set iff it doesn't reach forbidding state in the DFA. Now, from this DFA we can check:

1. If there is no cycle (except from forbidding state), then set is empty.
2. If there is a cycle, but no vertex in any cycle is reachable from vertex in a different cycle, then set is finite.
3. If there is a cycle reachable from a different cycle, but no intersecting cycles, then set is countable infinite.
4. If there are two intersecting cycles, the set has cardinality continuum.

The rest are undecidable. If you allow infinite number of restrictions for some base, let $B = \{2\}$ and $A_M = \{\{00, 11, x_M^1, x_M^2, \ldots\}\}$ where $x_M^i = 0^i$ if $M$ doesn't stop in exactly $i$ steps, and $x_M^i = 1$ if $M$ stops in exactly $i$ steps. If you allow infinite number of bases, let $B(n) = n + 1$, $A_M(n) = \varnothing$ if $M$ doesn't stop in exaclty $n$ steps, and $A_M(n) = \{0, 1, \ldots, (n-1)\}$ if it does.

Comment: No, as I say before, A(n) and B(n) must be computable. You can't use uncomputable algorithm to define A(n) or B(n).

Comment: They are computable in my construction - they are based on MT, and for every value they are guaranteed to stop.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I am not sure if I understand correct or not. So, it is like solving the halting problem for M in finite k step. But isn't the halting problem in finite k step decidable ? As for as I know, the true the halting problem is different from the halting problem in finite k step.

Comment: We need solve halting problem for $k$ steps to compute $A$, which is decidable. But answering if this $(A, B)$ give empty or non-empty is the same as solving general halting problem, which is not.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by decidable.

While it is true that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ is independent from the axioms of $\sf ZFC$, there is a real and meaningful sense in which we can say "The set of all real numbers satisfying $\varphi$ has the cardinality of the continuum", which means that the cardinality of this set is, in a sense, decidable.

Some sets we can define could, for example, be of sizes $\aleph_0,\aleph_1$, or $2^{\aleph_0}$, but $\sf ZFC$ could not decide which cardinality exactly. This, in a nutshell, why we sometimes say that "$\sf CH$ is true for Borel sets", as we can prove from $\sf ZFC$ that any Borel set is countable or has size $2^{\aleph_0}$.

So, why did I bring this up? If we look at the space of $n^\omega$, of all infinite sequences of digits $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, which is Borel isomorphic to the real numbers, then we can easily see that the set of all sequences which do not contain a certain string is going to be Borel. And therefore, it is either uncountable and therefore has size $2^{\aleph_0}$.

So, when can it be countable? Essentially when all your sequences must be determined in full by a finite amount of information. Which means that the finite string you've put as a restriction has prevented arbitrary switching between the other digits. In effect, this can only happen if you're working in a binary expansion and your string is either $10$ or $01$, which means that you cannot switch digits, so in the case of all binary strings that omit $10$ we have some number of $0$s followed by $1$s, as we cannot switch back. This is a countable set.

But, if you have at least two digits left to alternate, you will get a set of size continuum by obvious considerations.

Comment: Yes, for here, if it has cardinality of the continuum, it will be uncountable. From your answer, I think you prove that case (1.) is decidable. However, other case will be different from (1.). For example, case (2.) when some A(n) is infinite. Is it decidable to tell if that infinite A(n) is enough to restrict the "arbitrary switching between the other digits" or not ?

Comment: Firstly, "uncountable" is not particularly decidable. Not anymore than "non-empty". When you talk about something being decidable, it usually means that we can pinpoint, to a good extent, what the cardinality is. Often, this means identifying the index along the $\aleph$ numbers to which the cardinality corresponds; but sometimes it simply means identifying a concrete and "simple enough" set which will have the same cardinality. In this case, $\Bbb R$. As for the second question, if you want to avoid an infinite string, just intersect all the dense open sets which avoid it and apply BCT.